# How do I replace Js Global Variables and handle scala variables in Play Framework?

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, google-visualization

I have 3 map variables created by Java which are passed as 3 Scala variables to my Playframework's scala.html page.

This scala.html passes them to three global Js variables, which are then interpreted by GoogleCharts (Javascript).

Using one of the global variables in isolation displays a chart as expected, but two or three means no graph will show.

I know that global variables are bad practice, and I can see why. What is the simplest way to pass in these 3 scala variables to JS?

```
<head>
...
<script>
window.APP = {sMap: '@sMap'};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("/public/javascripts", "sChart.js")"></script>
<script>
window.APP = {eMap: '@eMap'};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("/public/javascripts", "eChart.js")"></script>
<script>
window.APP = {vMap: '@vMap'};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("/public/javascripts", "vChart.js")"></script>
</head>
```

Example for one of the js files:

```
function drawChart() {
var sMap = window.APP.sMap;
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
var mapString = sMap;
...;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when I declare the global variable from outside the function (I had it just inside the function before, which did work with just one variable, but stopped working with two or more).

What I have now looks like this:

```
var sMap = window.APP.sMap;

function drawChart() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
var mapString = sMap;
...;
```